# JSONException: Index 3 out of range - disable button before error

Tags: android, json

tutorial: [JSON Get data from MySql](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-json-tutorial-to-get-data-from-mysql-database/)

I followed this tutorial and everything went good. Even though the error not thrown, my app doesn't crash. But how to disable button after view the last array in JSON?

```
    public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v == nextBtn) {
        if(TRACK<marks.length()){
            TRACK++;
        }
        showData();


    }
    if (v == prevBtn) {
        if(TRACK>0){
            TRACK--;
        }
        showData();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT : 1**

Try below code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

if (v == nextBtn) {
    if(TRACK<marks.length()){

        if(TRACK==0)
        {
             //Enable previous button because you are incrementing the count
             prevBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        TRACK++;
        if(TRACK==(marks.length()-1))
        {
             //Disable next button
             v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    showData();

}
if (v == prevBtn) {
    if(TRACK>0){

        if(TRACK==(marks.length()-1))
        {
             //Enable next button because you are decrementing the count
             nextBtn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        TRACK--;
        if(TRACK==0)
        {
             //Disable previous button
             v.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
    showData();

}

}
```

**EDIT 2:**

for making prevButton disabled by default do it like this, Where you are doing `findViewById()`

```
prevButton = ()findViewById(); // Your findViewById code..!!
prevButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: almost there. for example, the JSON got 2 arrays. after show the 2nd array, the nextBtn should be disabled. But it is not yet disabled as it still 'think' the next array exist. After click nextBtn in view of 2nd array, the button disabled

Comment: need to reenable back the button

Comment: yes it works now. have to set prevBtn disabled by default first. thank you

Comment: If it worked please mark the answer as correct see : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/333378. For making prevButton by default disabled see my edit..!!